# Force importing module from current directory

Tags: python

I have package `p` that has modules `a` and `b`. `a` relies on `b`:

`b.py` contents:

```
import a
```

However I want to *ensure* that `b` imports my `a` module from the same `p` package directory and not just any `a` module from `PYTHONPATH`.

So I'm trying to change `b.py` like the following:

```
from . import a
```

This works as long as I import `b` when I'm outside of `p` package directory. Given the following files:

```
/tmp
    /p
       a.py
       b.py
       __init__.py
```

The following works:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ echo 'import p.b' | python
```

**The following does NOT work:**

```
$ cd /tmp/p
$ echo 'import b' | python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import a
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

**Why?**

P.S. I'm using Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After rereading the Python [import documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references), the correct answer to my original problem is:

*To ensure that `b` imports `a` from its own package its just enough to write the following in the `b`:*

```
import a
```

Here is the quote from the docs:

> The submodules often need to refer to each other. For example, the
>   surround module might use the echo module. In fact, **such references
>   are so common that the import statement first looks in the containing
>   package before looking in the standard module search path.**

**Note:** As J.F. Sebastian suggest in the comment below, use of implicit imports is not advised, and they are, in fact, gone in Python 3.

Comment: don't use implicit relative imports (they are gone in Python 3). Always use absolute import (`from p import a` (add `from __future__ import absolute_import` before it if there is `p/p.py` file)) or explicit relative import (`from . import a` (if it is not a `__main__` module)). Don't run scripts from inside a Python package directory; it prepends this directory to sys.path that might lead to the same module being available under different names that leads to bugs connected with module-level state (if you use implicit relative imports; it also shadows other toplevel modules in this case).

Answer (score 7):

Because there is an `__init__.py` file in `/p`. This file tells Python: "All modules in this folder are in the package `p`".

As long as the `__init__.py` file exists, you can import `b` as `p.b`, no matter where you are.

So the correct import in `b.py` would be: `import p.a`

Comment: Which version of Python? This behavior changed in the past.

Comment: Changing `b.py` as you've suggested. Now running `import b` yields `ImportError: No module named p.a`. Python 2.7.3

Comment: You should never use `import b` in such a scenario. Always use `import p.b` or make the necessary symbols available from `__init__.py` and `import p` to hide internal details.

Comment: Your problem is that you're mixing (old) relative imports and new package-based imports. The old imports were fickle, that's why the new style imports were introduced. See "Packages" in http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: So what is the correct way of accomplishing my task? `import p.a` in `b.py`? It works, but if I will ever want to rename p to something else, I'll have to change a lot of files...

Answer (score 0):

Relative imports only work within packages.

If you import `b` from where you are, there is no notion of a package, and thus there is no way for a relative import.

If you import `p.b`, it is module `b` within package `c`.

It is not the directory structure which matters, but the packages structure.