# How to import a module in a subdirectory that imports another module in that same subdirectory?

Tags: python, python-import

In a module that I import, I'm trying to import another module, that is located in that same directory.

My files look something like this...

```
project
├── main.py
└── app
    └── foo.py
    └── bar.py
```

**main.py**

```
import app.foo as Foo
```

**foo.py**

```
import bar
```

So now, when I run main.py, I get a

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bar'
```

There are so many similar questions, but none of them seem to be my exact situation.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: `from . import bar` should do the trick, but I'm not sure if this is really the recommended way :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute vs. explicit relative import of Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209641/absolute-vs-explicit-relative-import-of-python-module)

Comment: Relevant section of the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages and especially: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14216200/1025391

Answer (score 3):

Imports from .. or . should work:

```
from . import bar
```

remember to add `__init__.py` (empty file) inside app directory.

Edit: it could be done only if using foo and bar as modules. E.g. you would not be able to run "python foo.py" or "python foo.bar". Outside of app directory, you could try the code with:

```
python -m app.foo
```

(mind the lack of .py extension)

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly because when run `main.py` directly, Python would use the directory where `main.py` locates as the current running directory, thus when you `import bar` directly in `foo.py`, Python interpreter will try to find `bar` module in that running directory, where `bar.py` doesn't exist apparently. That is the reason why **relative import** is needed, as answered by [@Robert Szczelina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8221879/robert-szczelina).
If you run `foo.py` directly, the sentense `import bar` will be right.