# How to run a python script that's inside a subdirectory which has absolute imports

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following directory structure and files:

```
├── a
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── b.py
│   └── c
│       ├── c.py
└── main.py

# main.py
from a.b import b
print('i am main')

# a/b/b.py
from a.c import c
print('i am b')

# a/c/c.py
print('i am c')
```

The following works just fine and is expected.

```
» python3 main.py
i am c
i am b
i am main
```

However, if I go inside the directory `a/b` and run

```
python3 b.py
```

I get:

```
» python3 b.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from a.c import c
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'
```

And if I try to run it from the root of the project I get

```
» python3 a/b/b.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a/b/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from a.c import c
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'
```

It makes sense that it can't find the module which is one level above the directory but how would one run `a/b/b.py` script in this scenario?

Comment: Ugh, nvm I found out immediately after posting this. Answer is `python3 -m a.b.c`

Comment: There's a feature in which you can post an answer to your own question

Answer (score 0):

I'd still like a better explanation on why this works. But I got a hint for this from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44920246/1204312) answer.
You can run

```
python3 -m a.b.b
```

to run `b.py` which is inside `a/b/` directory.

Comment: Heh, coming to this after 4 years and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/1204312) pretty much summarizes why there's so much confusion with relative vs absolute imports. Please refer to the aforementioned link for detailed explaination. In short, it's how you run the top module. Running it as script (as I was trying to do here) will load that module as `__main__` instead of it's own name so hence the error.